# Relay with AT89S52 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, relay, diy, 8051

[image: This is circuit diagram]

I'm working on a project where I'm using 8051 microcontroller as a primary microcontroller which is interfacing with 4 relays. I have tested relays with two of my arduinos but when it comes to AT89S52 it hardly turn on a single relay.

I measured output voltage of Arduino pins with was connected to relays which was 5.12 V and 5.8 V respectively but when it comes it AT89S52 it gives 4.86 V. My relays need 5 VDC as an input which I'm giving externally and grounding nicely everything.

This is my relay board
[image: This is my relay board]

I'm powering Arduinos by my PC and AT89S52 is powered by 12 V which is converted to 5 V with LM7805.

Need help!

Comment: A microcontroller can't drive relays directly, buffer the signal with a transistor, for example.

Comment: You need to provide schematics what you connected to where and how. Otherwise we don't know what the error is and where so we can't provide an answer how to fix it. Although you say you need help, you don't say with what exactly you need help with and you also don't ask a question, so edit in the question you want answered.

Comment: Hi, sorry for bad expression. I have updated my question and if I could else provide anything then please let me know.

Comment: Missing base resistors and flyback diode across each coil. Depending on coil current, BJTs may be a bad idea unless they have high beta. Go with MOSFETs.

Comment: @winny such as? In my case, relay board works fine with arduino board but it seems it lacks input pin voltage from AT89S52  microcontroller to relay.

Comment: 4.86V is no problem. The problem is somewhere else. I noticed that your transistors have no resistors in series with their bases - you need those or the microcontroller outputs will be overloaded.

Comment: Without the resistor you would not measure 4.86V on the output, it would be more like 0.7V to 1.0V.  Perhaps you have a wiring problem and the transistor is not getting the signal from the output.

Comment: Its there! There is 1k res on base.  Did you check second image from post which is in link format? https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Clp.png

Comment: I also checked the first image from post which does not have them.

Comment: You now have two different schematics. Which one is which?

Comment: oh, what is RL1(C1) and RL2(C1) etc.?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Clp.png This is actual schematic image, first one was made for simulation in proteus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [AT89S52 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc1919.pdf):

[image]

The device only guarantees 60 uA (and that at 2.4 volts output).  This is not enough current to drive your relay board properly.  You should replace Q1 on your relay board with a MOSFET with a logic-level gate threshold voltage.

Comment: Can you please name few of them? a MOSFET with a logic-level gate threshold voltage.

Comment: Look for a N-channel enhancement mode MOSFET in a TO92 package with a gate threshold voltage of around 1 volt.  2N7002 will probably work

Comment: I have 2N7000 FET - N-Channel Enhancement Mode FET TO-92 Package. Will this work?

Comment: It should be fine - the output high voltage is 0.9 Vcc (4.5 volts) at 10uA, and you will be providing less than 1 uA.

Comment: I was going through datasheet of 2N7000 and found ||Gate threshold voltage||V DS = VGS, ID = 250 μA|| 1V || 2.1V || 3V  I didn't understand what is V DS = VGS, ID = 250 μA as my microcontroller can source only 60μA according to its datasheet.

Comment: How do I have to connect 2N7000 mosfet? I connected as in place of BC548 but as I power on relay board, the coil turns on automatically without input pin. Here's link of my relay circuit https://ibb.co/ncF6QnH

Comment: You can't let the gate of a MOSFET float, so when your board is unconnected it may turn on.  You will need to have a resistor between gate and ground; I think something around 50-100K.

Comment: I tried but coil still turns on as I supply 5v to module. Here's my schema: https://ibb.co/H4xwsBH

Comment: looks good to me - try simulating with LTSpice or similar.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks a lot!!! I made it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that circuit won't work, for many reasons.

Typical 8051 MCUs have open drain outputs, they can sink current in but can't source much current, if any at all.

You may want a high side PNP driver for the relay, and a base resistor to limit the current. You may also want to add a flyback diode for the coil so the transistor does not damage the first time you turn the relay off.